# How can I Countunique only first word when formular doesn't accept Æ, Ø, Å

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[In this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fb62Z74qZG_IilcbB3lam60ZJh68VrXv4sxqOhEkx5c/edit?usp=sharing) I'm trying to count different destination. It seems to be problematic when it comes to Æ, Ø and Å.

The formula

```
=COUNTA(B3:B12) & " travels to " & COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IF(LEN(B3:B12);IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B3:B12);"^([\w\-]+)");B3:B12);))))&" differenct countries"
```

How can I make the formula accept these characters?

Comment: Oh, I get it. You're getting bamboozled by the lowercase characters. Those characters all have lowercase forms, but I don't think the Regex engine knows about it. So try to add the lowercase forms to the regex or use upper instead of lower.

Comment: Still no success...

Comment: Looks fine to me? You have 5 different countries, and 8 cells have values.

Comment: 6 different countries only counted as 5 tho

Comment: Iceland is on there twice.

Comment: I don't know what to say but I think you're right.

Comment: Based on your mixed data, your formula will fail when you have countries that have two word names, (for example "New Zealand", "New Caledonia", "South Korea" etc.) so unless you can give examples that are representative of what you are trying to achieve, then it will be difficult to give a definitive solution. However, based on your current identified list, this will do the same `"\w+"`

Comment: I see "\w+" is way more clean, thank you. Would it be a whole new game to include New Zealand + other examples?

Comment: @AllanBech For your initial enquiry, please see the answer i have provided below.

Comment: @AllanBech please see the last `EDIT 2` i have just added for solution regarding two word place names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `TRIM(IF(LEN(B3:B14);IFERROR(` is unnecessary in your formula.

the formula can be contracted to:

```
=COUNTA(B3:B14) & " travels to " & COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B3:B14);"\w+")))&" different countries"
```

EDIT:

if there will be any blanks in the data, then `TRIM(IF(LEN(B3:B14);` is unnecessary, and the formula can be contracted to:

```
=COUNTA(B3:B14) & " travels to " & COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B3:B14);"\w+");)))&" different countries"
```

EDIT 2:

in regards to your enquiry about countries with two word names, the following formula uses `"[^,\d(]*"` to find everything up to the first comma, number, or opening bracket, then uses `TRIM` to remove trailing spaces, so can return the full name.

```
=COUNTA(B3:B16) & " travels to " & COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B3:B16);"[^,\d(]*"));)))&" different countries"
```

Comment: That's a very smart way to solve this challenge. Thank You so much.